# When I Intent to open standard video player, can i strip the gallery interface or reroute it?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I open a video in my application with an intent to the default player.  It shows a gallery in the top left that would go to the gallery for the device which I don't want.  Is there a way to customize it so that either that icon will fire the equivalent of the back button OR just remove it altogether?

I was thinking there were params in the intent or something that would be interpreted by the activity.

**Goal:**  I want to be able to launch default player without the top nav bar.  I feel it is something that i should just create my own VideoView for, instead of using a default player.  I just didnt want the gallery button to point back to the gallery.  Feel that might be some confusion.

I havent seen anything that told me of optional parameters i could pass into the video activity.

Comment: Even if you could find optional parameters to pass into the video activity, you can't guarantee that all devices will have the same default player, much less the same params. I agree you should probably just use a VideoView.

Comment: Sounds like what i will have to do.  I figure that when you do a VideoView, i can sort of define what shows up in the playback, such as play,pause, skip ahead, rewind, and all that stuff.